# Send sync message from IpcMain to IpcRenderer - Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

In [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron), It is possible to send sync message from IpcRenderer to IpcMain via `ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')`.

Also possible to send **async** message from IpcMain to IpcRenderer using `window.webContents.send('ping', 'whoooooooh!')`

but is there any way to send **sync** message from IpcMain to IpcRenderer?

Comment: I believe you cannot, because you would block the main node thread this way, which runs renderer processes, too. But I guess you can achieve the same in async fashion by replying in your renderer callback with `event.sender.send` and wait that up in main

Answer (score 24):

There is no such functionality of `ipcMain` <sup>*</sup>. However, you can achieve almost the same result asynchronously with the following steps:

- Place your code which you would run only after the synchronous call in an `ipcMain` callback.
- Reply to ipc message in renderer process with the result using `event.sender.send`

A dummy example of calculating sum using this approach looks like the following:

*main.js*

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow()
  // have to run "sync", that is only after result is ready
  const doJobWithResult = (res) => {
    console.log(res)
  }
  win.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    win.webContents
    .send('sum-request', 23, 98, 3, 61)
    ipcMain.once('sum-reply', (event, sum) => {
      doJobWithResult(sum)
    })
  })
  win.loadURL(path.resolve(__dirname, 'test.html'))
})
```

*renderer.js (referred from test.html)*

```js
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

window.onload = () => {
  const add = (a, b) => {
    return a + b
  }
  ipcRenderer.on('sum-request', (event, ...args) => {
    event.sender.send('sum-reply', [...args].reduce(add, 0))
  })
}
```

---

<sub>* I guess the main reason for this is that synchronous calls from the main process to the renderer process would cause the main nodejs process to wait, which is also responsible for running the renderer processes.</sub>

Comment: To avoid the doJobWithResult callback and have things more in sequence,
I would suggest this:
async function sum(...args) {
 win.webContents.send('sum-request', ...args);
 return await = new Promise((resolve) => {
   ipcMain.once('sum-reply', (event, sum) => {
      resolve(sum);
    })
  });
}
// do something first
console.log(sum(23, 98, 3, 61));
// do something next

This is the pattern I use to simulate this missing win.webContents.sendSync

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way to access Main Process Objects in renderer process(sync)

```
// In renderer process (web page).
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
let exec = eval => ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', eval);
exec("win.setSize(500,500)");
console.log(exec("win.getBounds()"));
console.log(exec("app.getVersion()"));

// In the Main process.
ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  event.returnValue = eval(arg);
})
```

It's the way to send msg from Main process to renderer process.(Official example)

```
// In renderer process (web page).
ipcRenderer.on('test', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg) // 123
})
// In the Main process.(after loaded you can send msg to renderer process)
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.webContents.send('test',123);
})
```

Comment: I'd like to note that allowing unsanitized input from the renderer process to be run in the main process is a huge security risk. If you were to load any web page, you could easily end up with remote code execution...

Answer (score 13):

I was trying to do the same, and the closest I got, was sending first the message from the IPCRenderer and then return what you want from the IPCMain event received is with this code snippet:

```js
// In renderer process (web page).
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')); // prints "pong"

// In the Main process.
ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', function(event, arg) {
  console.log(arg);  // prints "ping"
  event.returnValue = 'pong';
});
```

Comment: This answer starts with the renderer process. Can you make it such that the sync message is first sent from the main process?

Answer (score -4):

Yes it is possible to send send sync message from IpcRenderer to IpcMain

```
let {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

ipcRenderer.sendSync('sync', 'Im the message from the renderer');


// Listen for sync message from renderer process
ipcMain.on('sync', (event, arg) => {  
    console.log(arg);   // Print Im the message from the renderer
});
```

I suggest you to visit this post, Of VJEKOSLAV RATKAJEC, he explains very well the communication between de ipcMain to ipcRenderer and viceversa.

Link: http://electron.rocks/different-ways-to-communicate-between-main-and-renderer-process/

Comment: The question was how to send from ipcMain TO ipcRenderer. What you've described is default behavior.

Comment: Sorry Wibby, the things is that they had changed the topic or the question of this issue, I'll fix it later.