# Are Electron ipc messages ordered?

Tags: electron, ipc, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

Are there any ordering guarantees of ipc messages in Electron? If so, what are they?

For instance, in main:

```
window.webContents.send('channel-a', 1)
window.webContents.send('channel-a', 2)
```

And in the renderer:

```
ipcRenderer.on('channel-a', (_event, num) => console.log(num))
```

Are the messages always delivered in order to the renderer (such that 1 comes before 2 in the example above)?

If so, are they also always ordered if the messages are on *different channels* (e.g. by changing `channel-a` to `channel-b` in one of the lines above)?

Comment: I guess implementing a hacky solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47653853/9698583) is currently the only way to guarantee order. I don't know if there's a better way.